# MySQL How to check if a value is an integer or a text in a field

Tags: php, mysql, text, integer

Please I have a field in my data base with a type `text`, but that could contains some `integer` value.

When I select data from this field I should distinct if is an integer or text (Just to handle mysql operation like < or >) So I've tried :

```
$clause = "";
if(is_int($_GET['f']))
   $clause = " AND myValue < ".$_GET['f']."  ";
else
   $clause = " AND myValue = '".$_GET['f']."'  ";

$ds->query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 1 ".$clause);
```

please note the **quote** in case it wasn't an integer.

But this doesn't work and it's normal I think because the field has a type `text`.

Please have you any solution for this problem. Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you can have both integers and strings in a DB field, and you have to interpret the two differently you have done something very wrong. This is not a normalized structure. I recommend a redesign. Create two columns for the different data, and use it accordingly

Comment: Strongly agree with @ppeterka. Have a column for varchar, and another for int.

Comment: what is the meaning of this field, this text and these integers?

Comment: Can you paste the table structure here.

Comment: you also have to check the db field if is numeric. you can fiddle out here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34436/4 ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `text` type column always treats its values as text (a string), so regardless of what value is stored, you need to enclose it in `'`. MySQL can compare a number as a string.

Also, `is_int` is not suitable for checking `$_GET` values, as they are considered strings. Use `is_numeric` instead.

But notice the comments to your question, a redesign is more suitable if you need to store integers and/or strings separately in your database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
            $clause = "";
        if(is_numeric($_GET['f']))
           $clause = " AND myValue < ".$_GET['f']."  ";
        else
           $clause = " AND myValue = '".$_GET['f']."'  ";

        $ds->query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 1 ".$clause);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an solution for your. 
Mysql handle datatypes and operators sometimes implicit for example .

```
SELECT 1+'1';
   -> 2
```

I am playing around with my database. Column a as varchar. Then i enter 5 values from 1 to 5. If i querye `select * from mytable where a > 2`  i get the right result (the entry '1' is not displayed. if i enter a new row with an character like "b" this character is not in the result. 
Or you can play around with explicit type casting.

Kind Regards